# video player on ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, video, media

I got a bq m10 tablet and I found that the desktop media player app "VLC" doesn't run normally because of low hardware. So I have to find another tablet app to play my videos and I cant find one suitable.
My requirement are as follows:

a) Support more video file just like .mkv.

b) Support subtitles, just like .srt file.

c) Remember the last file which has played, and also the played time.

So my question is which media player should I chose?thank you.